# Wordpress + Isotope: how to give different widths to each entry?

Tags: loop

I am using Isotope.js in my portfolio to show my work.

Through my loop I am defining a priori (using Bootstrap) the width of each entry, and that is the same for all my entries.

**How can I assign different widths (col-*) to each post from time to time?**

```
<div class="row grid">
            <div class="grid-sizer col-12 col-sm-6"></div><!-- .grid-sizer per Isotope -->
            <?php query_posts(array(  'post_type' => 'portfolio', 'author' => get_the_author_meta('ID'), 'showposts' => 10  ) ); ?>
            <?php while (have_posts()) : the_post(); 
            $termsArray = get_the_terms( $post->ID, $taxonomy );  //Get the terms for this particular item
            $termsString = ""; //initialize the string that will contain the terms
                foreach ( $termsArray as $term ) { // for each term 
                    $termsString .= $term->slug.' '; //create a string that has all the slugs 
                }
                ?>
            <div class="col-12 col-sm-6 <?php echo $termsString; ?> grid-item wow fadeInUp">
                <article id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" <?php post_class('card'); ?>>
                    <?php echo get_the_post_thumbnail($post_id, 'large', array('class' => 'img-fluid card-img-top')); ?>
                    <div class="overlay"></div>
                    <div class="card-body text-right">
                        <h6 class="card-title"><?php the_title(); ?></h6>
                        <p>Text description for this item</p>
                    </div>
                    <a class="card-link" href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php the_title_attribute(); ?>"></a>  
                </article>
            </div>
                    <?php endwhile; ?>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

On the div that immediately wraps each post, you can use php to randomize the values instead of hardcoding the `col-12` and `col-sm-6` classes.

For example, you could change

```
<div class="col-12 col-sm-6 <?php echo $termsString; ?> grid-item wow fadeInUp">
```

to reflect the randomizer and then its result:

```
<?php
  $randomColClasses = 'col-' . rand(8,12); //random value between 8-12
  $randomColClasses .= ' col-sm-' . rand(4,8); //random value between 4-8
?>

<div class="<?php echo $randomColClasses . ' ' . $termsString; ?> grid-item wow fadeInUp">
```

Comment: Hello, thanks for answering.
I just tried it, and it's not a good option for Isotope.js, because it breaks the layout, so it could assign to the first column the value 8 and to the second column the value 6, exceeding the maximum of 12, and putting the second column below the first.

I have seen in some sites that they manage to change the width of each column, but I can not understand how they have achieved it through.
The only thing that occurs to me is to pass these classes (col-12, col-sm-6, col-md- 8 etc ..) manually every time a post is uploaded. Is this possible to do?

Comment: If you predetermine 2 or 3 grid item widths with bootstrap column classes, you can set randomize between those 3 by getting a random number between 1-3 and then using a switch/if statement to set col-A, col-sm-A, col-B, col-sm-B, etc.  Keep in mind, you'll want to pick column sizes that add up to the overall 12 columns in bootstrap fairly frequently.  So maybe randomize to generate col-sm-2, col-sm-4.